# Get Comments with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser

Tags: php, parsing, dom, html-parsing

I'm working with PHP Simple HTML DOM Parser.

I was wondering if it is possible to extract the HTML comments (`<!-- -->`).

Can you?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Directly from their docs:

```
// Find all comment (<!--...-->) blocks 
$es = $html->find('comment');
```

http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/manual.htm

Comment: The link provided doesn't work anymore.