# simple_html_dom finding input in html commented section

Tags: php, html, dom, simple-html-dom

I need to find an html input that is in an html commented section

```
<!-- <input type="hidden" name="ab_cde" value="12345" /> -->
```

the code

```
foreach($html->find('input') as $element) 
    {   

    }
```

is not working to find it. How can it be done?

Comment: Does this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11977896/get-comments-with-php-simple-html-dom-parser

Comment: I suppose it does, but I guess the commentaries can't be treated as html but as a string?

Comment: Ok, got the answer from the post, I apply that and then $doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML(string);  . Thanks!

Comment: Yep, comments are comments, there's no reason to assume there is HTML in there. You can of course parse the comment again or look for HTML markers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can do via `$html->find('comment')`
and then use an regular expression for your input in there or initialize the comments content as another html object (http://php.net/manual/en/domdocument.loadhtml.php) to be searched like you tried before.